# Dataframe values length giving nan in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have dataframe with Date column and year as values, I want to display length, but its showing as nan.

The script:

```
dataAll['Date'].unique()
Output: array([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2011, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2002,2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2017, 2001, 2000], dtype=object)

dataAll['Date'].str.len().unique()
Output: array([ nan])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...let's just say I try to recreate your example.

```
years= [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2011, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2017, 2001, 2000]
years = [str(x) for x in years]

dataAll = pd.DataFrame({'Date':years})
dataAll['Date'].str.len().unique()
Out[63]: array([4], dtype=int64)
```

In other words, the code is working as expected, but the data in your dataAll.Date is not strings.

Now I will do exactly the same, but with different data representations, which will fail twice:

```
years= [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2011, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2017, 2001, 2000]

dataAll = pd.DataFrame({'Date':years})
dataAll['Date'].str.len().unique()
Out[68]: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

years= [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2011, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2017, 2001, 2000]

dataAll = pd.DataFrame({'Date':years}, dtype=object)
dataAll['Date'].str.len().unique()
Out[73]: array([ nan])
```

And the fix:

```
dataAll.Date = dataAll.Date.astype(str)

dataAll['Date'].str.len().unique()
Out[75]: array([4], dtype=int64)
```